# Why pgadmin dont enter in admin panel?

Tags: windows, postgresql, pgadmin

I install postgresql-12.4 on my win pc. When i'm trying to enter into admin panel (pgadmin) i cathcing message:
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5433? could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5433?

I have 2 users on my pc. Admin and another user with adming rights. Under admin profile pgadmin works good, uder another user profile pgadmin throws error message. In services server is running.

Answer (score 0):

According this previous post on [Stackoverlfow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57109494/unable-to-connect-to-server-pgadmin-4?answertab=votes#tab-top)

- Enter your server’s IP address in the “Hostname/ Address” field. Default is localhost.
- Specify the “Port” as “5432”.
- Enter the name of the database in the “Database Maintenance” field.
- Enter your username as postgres and password (use the same password you used when previously configuring the server to accept remote connections) for the database.
- Click “Save” to apply the configuration.